# Use google.protobuf.Timestamp in PubSub schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to create a PubSub schema which looks like

```
syntax = "proto3";
package proto;

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyEvent {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp timestamp = 1;
    // other fields
}
```

However, when validating the schema I get an error message saying

```
Invalid Protocol Buffer schema. Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" has not been loaded.
```

Answer (score 2):

Imports are not currently supported with Pub/Sub schema. The message specified in a schema must be completely self-contained.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Do you happen to know of a way to conveniently make a .proto file self containted by replacing its imports with the content of the import (recursively)?